# javascript generate square wave sound

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio, windows-phone-8

I want to generate a square wave sound using a signal "1 0 0 0". Each code (0,1) has a pattern as shown in [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByfrAMlECtveNUF5RjlsTWtsUjQ/view?usp=sharing).

For example, code 1 will produce a sound for 500µs and than stops for 1000µs.The signals should go from zero to maximum positive amplitude and will not have any negative amplitude.The frequency of the sound is 10KHz.

Basically i need to generate this sound from mobile devices (iPhone, Android and Windows phone 8). I am using Cordova framework. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
var frequency = 10000;
var data = {
    1: {duration:500, sleep:1000},
    0: {duration:500, sleep:500}
}
var audio = new window.webkitAudioContext();


//function creates an Oscillator. In this code we are creating an Oscillator for every tune, which help you control the gain. 
//If you want, you can try creating the Oscillator once and stopping/starting it as you wish.
function createOscillator(freq, duration) {
    var attack = 10, //duration it will take to increase volume full sound volume, makes it more natural
        gain = audio.createGain(),
        osc = audio.createOscillator();

    gain.connect(audio.destination);
    gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0, audio.currentTime); //change to "1" if you're not fadding in/out
    gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, audio.currentTime + attack / 1000); //remove if you don't want to fade in
    gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, audio.currentTime + duration / 1000); //remove if you don't want to fade out

    osc.frequency.value = freq;
    osc.type = "square";
    osc.connect(gain);
    osc.start(0);


    setTimeout(function() {
        osc.stop(0);
        osc.disconnect(gain);
        gain.disconnect(audio.destination);
    }, duration)
}

function play() {
    //your pattern
    var song = [1,0,1,1];       

    timeForNext = 0;
    for (i=0;i<song.length;i++){            
        duration = data[song[i]].duration;
        //use timeout to delay next tune sound
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            createOscillator(frequency, duration);
        },timeForNext);         
        timeForNext+=data[song[i]].sleep;       
    }
}

//play the music
play();
```

This link has some good info http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=3896 I used it to create a piano app with Cordova a while ago. Still haven't published it though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think so instead of "timeForNext+=data[song[i]].sleep;", we have to write "timeForNext = timeForNext + data[signal[i]].duration + data[signal[i]].sleep;" to get the proper sleep delay.